# How do I automate a Java Applet using the Java Access Bridge?

Tags: java, automation, applet, java-access-bridge

I need to automate a Java Applet which sits inside an IE only website. I know I can use the [Java Access Bridge](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/access/enable_and_test.html) to interact with Java applications but I'm having trouble finding out how to hook it up to an Applet.

I am aware of a Java Bridge method called `GetAccessibleContextFromHWND(..)` which I thought I may be able to use. Unfortunately when I use Spy++ to try and get the Applet's HWND, I comes back blank so it seems this can not be done using the usual `FindWindow(..)` Windows API function.

How can I access and control Java Applets using the Java Access Bridge?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why do you make an IE only website when it is obsolete since whenever?

Comment: I didn't make it. It has probably been probably been kicking around since the 90's. I just need to automate it :)

Comment: Related: [C# Automation using Java Access Bridge](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19057985/3357935) & [How to automate java application with autohotkey](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17564086/3357935)

Comment: Which version of IE are you using?

Comment: @TarunLalwani I don't know about OP, but I've been using IE 10

Answer (score 0):

```
1.Find Applet tag from HTML page and get position(Height/Width) of it.

2.Move your cursor toward Applet center position with reference of IE window.

3.Use **getAccessibleContextAt** API and use Applet x,y position.

4.Get Accesiblecontext from above API.

5.Iterate to root level Accesiblecontext. Finally you will get first object of Applet window.
```