# Java Access Bridge c# unable to activate field, set text, click etc

Tags: c#, automation, java-access-bridge

I am working on the **Java Access Bridge in c#** for some time now.
I finally got it to working, partly.

- I can properly initialize the access bridge.
- I can use the GetAccessibleContextFromHWND to get vmid and javaObjectHandle.
- I can also use GetAccessibleContextInfo to get accessibleContextInfo.
- Lastly, I can enumerate the children and find a node that interests me.

How do I take it from there?
**I tried to do things like set text, click or get text but was unable.**
I used the below code that was mentioned in another question, [Automation using Java Access Bridge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19057985/automation-using-java-access-bridge)

**Set text:**

```
public string Text
{
    get 
    {
        return GetText();
    }
    set
    {
        if (!API.setTextContents(this.VmId, this.Context, value))
            throw new AccessibilityException("Error setting text");
    }
}

private string GetText()
{
    System.Text.StringBuilder sbText = new System.Text.StringBuilder();

    int caretIndex = 0;

    while (true)
    {
        API.AccessibleTextItemsInfo ti = new API.AccessibleTextItemsInfo();
        if (!API.getAccessibleTextItems(this.VmId, this.Context, ref ti, caretIndex))
            throw new AccessibilityException("Error getting accessible text item information");

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ti.sentence))
            sbText.Append(ti.sentence);
        else               
            break;

        caretIndex = sbText.Length;

    }
```

**Click on a button:**

```
public void Press()
{
    DoAction("click");
}

protected void DoAction(params string[] actions)
{
    API.AccessibleActionsToDo todo = new API.AccessibleActionsToDo()
    {
        actionInfo = new API.AccessibleActionInfo[API.MAX_ACTIONS_TO_DO],
        actionsCount = actions.Length,
    };

    for (int i = 0, n = Math.Min(actions.Length, API.MAX_ACTIONS_TO_DO); i < n; i++)
        todo.actionInfo[i].name = actions[i];

    Int32 failure = 0;
    if (!API.doAccessibleActions(this.VmId, this.Context, ref todo, ref failure))
        throw new AccessibilityException("Error performing action");
}
```

Any ideas would be much appreciated.
Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

`doAccessibleActions` actually this function is not working at all, so, you must combine win32 api for doing alternative such as: `set text` => `send key`, scroll ...